# How can I search emails until I encounter a certain email that has a specific field?

Tags: python, email, imap

My code monitors an email inbox periodically.

The code sample:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=server, port=port)
mail.login(account, password)
mail.select()
typ, msgnums = self.mail.search(*WHERE I WANT TO IMPLEMENT*)
```

After one monitoring ends, I save the last seen email's 'Message-ID' field.

For the next monitoring, I want to search the inbox from the latest email to the email that has the 'Message-ID' field.

How can I make this happen?

I've checked imap search criteria, and couldn't find any that can be used for this case.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I added a sample.

Comment: Read through [`[python] [imap] search`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Bpython%5D+%5Bimap%5D+search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After one monitoring ends, I save the last seen email's 'Message-ID' field.

> For the next monitoring, I want to search the inbox from the latest email to the email that has the 'Message-ID' field.

You can't do that on the `Message-ID` field because not all smtp providers use dates or increasing serial numbers in the message id. So `Message-ID: XYZ` can be before or after `Message-ID: ABC`. See [`Message-ID` vs `UID`, on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37163120/1431750).

1. `UID` works, if used carefully:

> The combination of mailbox name, `UIDVALIDITY`, and `UID` must refer to a single immutable message on that server forever.

Using the example from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148609/1431750):

```
    mail.search('UID 2000:*')
```

2. You could also use the Date fields of the last email checked. Referring to [one more SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406710/1431750) and the [SEARCH section of RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4):

   ```
    typ, msgnums = mail.search('SINCE 1-Feb-1994')
   ```

Make sure dates are in that format. You may have an overlap of messages returned within the same 24 hour period, so you'll need to save `UIDs` also, to avoid re-fetching those.

3. If your client is the only one accessing the inbox, you could also use `UNSEEN` but I don't recommend it:

   ```
    mail.search('UNSEEN')
   ```